# Adding decorator to index type

Tags: typescript

I'm trying without success to decorate an index type:

```
export class Translation {
  @Field()
  @Expose()
  [key: string]: string;
}
```

But getting `Decorators are not valid here` error. It's clear that on the compilation phase there are no any fields for decorating. Do we have a workaround for this? Thanks.

Comment: Decorators are executed when the class constructor is created. By the time any instances are created, they have already run and done their thing. And property decorators decorate a _specific_ property. So you couldn't possible run a property decorator on properties that you don't yet know the names of. I don't think whatever you are trying to do will work this way.